# Recursively Identifying Sorted Lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion, python-3.x

As a recursion practice exercise, I am writing a Python function that recursively identifies if the input list is sorted from least to greatest, real numbers only, and then returns a Boolean value.

My code is:

```
def det_sorted(listA):
    if len(listA) == 1:
        return(True)
    else:
        if listA[0] <= det_sorted(listA[1:]):
            return(True)
        elif listA[0] > det_sorted(listA[1:]):
            return(False)
```

This function always returns 'False.' The general question: how do I iterate recursively through the list correctly? My specific question: what have I done wrong here?

Comment: My first answer is "you don't". Since you already have `sorted()` available, anything else is more complicated and expensive.

Comment: An easy way to see what's going wrong is to realize that any call to `sorted()` will return either `True` or `False`, and your `if` statements are doing the inequality check on `True` or `False`. Which isn't what you want.

Comment: You shouldn't call it `sorted()` because that'll shadow the built-in function. `is_sorted()` will do fine.

Comment: 1) Never use names already taken by built-ins 2) Predicates(i.e. functions that return `True`/`False` for given conditions on the inputs) should have names that start with a verb in present tense: e.g. `is_sorted`, `has_fruits`, `can_kill`, `has_moo_powers`. Functions that perform actions should have verbs/sentences as names: `sort`, `grow_fruits`, `kill`, `use_moo_powers`. Using past tense may suggest the fact that the operation is not in-place (e.g. `sorted` suggests that the value returned is sorted, not that the original sequence is being sorted).

Comment: @bakuriu Aahh. That's good to know. I will make those changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are close , you want to call the recursion for the return

```
else:
        if listA[0] <= listA[1]:
             return sorted(listA[1:])
```

or you could combine both statements into the return (and get rid of the else)

```
return  listA[0] <= listA[1] and sorted(listA[1:])
```

Comment: The second set of code works. The first edited code returns 'None' instead of 'False,' though.

Comment: none is a falsy value ... so saying `if None:` is essentially the same as saying `if False` ... but it wont match `if None == False`\

Comment: Definitely. The code works the same, but knowing the output is important as well.

Answer (score 2):

@Joran Beasley's answer is correct, but here's another solution to the problem that should be a bit quicker:

```
def is_sorted(l, prev=None):
    if l:
        if prev is None: return is_sorted(l[1:], l[0])
        else: return l[0] > prev and is_sorted(l[1:], l[0])
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: You can replace `len(l) == 0` with just `l`.

Comment: @Blender thanks, I originally had it as `len(l) <= 1` and forgot to change it when I fixed that.

Comment: @Blender `if l:` will evaluate as `True` so long as `len(l)` is at least 1. Don't you mean `if not l`?

Comment: Woops!  Fixed.  I switched the order of the statements because I prefer to write `if l` to `if not l`

Comment: Note that the usage of `None` for negative infinity and `()` for positive infinity in Python 2 doesn't work in Python 3. In Python 2 `() > 0 > None` is `True` where as in Python 3, it results in `TypeError: unorderable types`. And due to that the code in this answer will work fine on Python 2 but as the OP's tag's specify Python 3 this will not work.

Comment: That is interesting. I did notice that code did not work on test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very explicit script that works.

```
def det_sorted(listA):
    if len(listA) == 1:
        return(True)
    else:
        if det_sorted(listA[1:]) == True:
            if listA[0] <= listA[1]:
                return(True)
            elif listA[0] > listA[1]:
                return(False)
        else:
            return(False)
```

Comment: Although a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't take into consideration the case where `listA` is empty, which should evaluate as sorted. So the full function should look like this:

```
def is_sorted(listA):
  if len(listA) == 0 and len(listA) == 1:
      return True
  else:
      return  listA[0] <= listA[1] and is_sorted(listA[1:])
```

This could be shortened a bit:

```
def is_sorted(listA):
  if not (listA and listA[1:])
      return True
  return listA[0] <= listA[1] and is_sorted(listA[1:])
```